# Change Android 5.0 scrollbar color

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

Does anyone know how to change the color of scrollbars within Theme.Material to something other than colorControlNormal? If you go and look in themes_material you can see that there are certain Scrollbar attributes, but there is no direct way to override the scrollbar color, only the entire drawable. For my purposes, I want to keep the scrollbar drawable the same as the one that the system is using (same nine-patch), I just want to tint it a different color than my colorControlNormal color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that you could override the entire scrollbarThumbVertical or scrollbarThumbHorizontal attributes within your own theme to a different drawable; within you AppTheme it would look like:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material">
    <item name="android:scrollbarThumbVertical">@drawable/scrollbar_handle_material</item>
</style>
```

and then within your drawable-v21 folder you would have the same xml found here from the system:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2014 The Android Open Source Project
 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 You may obtain a copy of the License at
      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.
 -->

<nine-patch xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:src="@drawable/scrollbar_handle_mtrl_alpha"
   android:tint="#A4A4A4" />
```

where you would set the tint color to the color you want your scrollbars to be on 5.0+ devices. Since Google does not make the scrollbar_handle_mtrl_alpha asset public to access, you need to go and pull it from the PATH_TO_ANDROID_SDK/platforms/android-21/data/res/drawable-xxhdpi/scrollbar_handle_material_alpha along with all of the other densities you want to provide. I will put the drawable-xxhdpi asset here for reference:

[image]

Please let me know if you guys find any other way to do this without having to override so many things.